# Updating bounds of custom CALayer in drawLayer:inContext:

Tags: ios, calayer, layer, quartz-2d

I've got a custom layer which is sub-layer of something else. The problem is, my layer can't know it's size until I'm in `drawLayer:inContext:`.

When I *don't* change the bounds/frame of my layer everything draws perfectly.

When I add in the the line to change frame/bounds, my background looks perfect, but my content doesn't exist. It looks like the content is clipping off the original bounds instead of the new (bigger) bounds so I see nothing but the background.

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context {   
    CGFloat initialGraphContentsWidth = graph.frame.size.width - graph.leftMargin;
    CGFloat initialGraphContentsHeight = graph.frame.size.height - graph.bottomMargin - graphHelper.topMargin;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, initialGraphContentsWidth, initialGraphContentsHeight);
    self.position = CGPointMake(graphHelper.leftMargin + 1, graphHelper.topMargin + 1);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20));
}
```

So how to I dynamically change my bounds and still get my content to appear?

I tried setting up a `CATransaction` with a duration of 0, but that did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` after you have updated the frame/bounds?

So for instance if you had a `CALayer` called `layer`, you could try the following:

```
layer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 100, 300);
// tell the layer that it needs to refreshed
[layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` causes in `drawLayer:inContext` being called.  So calling `setNeedsDisplay` would at worst result in a infinite draw loop and best Apple's code would recognize the issue and just ignore the call.